# $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\cos(2x)e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

how do I calculate this integral or more generally how do I calculate:

$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n\cos(2x)e^{-x^2}dx$$

I tried to use the following formulas that I'm familiar with:

i) $\displaystyle \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ne^{-ax^2}dx=\begin{cases} \dfrac {(n-1)!!\sqrt \pi}{2^{n/2}a^{(n+1)/2}} &\mbox{if } n \text{ is even}\\0 &\mbox{if } n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$

ii) $\displaystyle \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(ax)e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt \pi e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$

and somehow integrate by parts but it didn't work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the negative second derivative of your result in ii):

$$-\frac{d^2}{da^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \cos{a x} \, e^{-x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, x^2 \cos{a x} \, e^{-x^2} $$

Because the integrals are convergent, the switching of the order of integration and differentiation is justified.

Comment: thanks. this should do the trick. I keep forgetting to always try differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Gee that was fast, but the justification of changing differentiation and integration seems fishy to me. For sure it is allowed as we are having a Schwartz-function here and hence totally can use dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Of course you are right.  However, generally speaking, absolute convergence of resulting integrals is a good rule of thumb for justifying the interchange of derivatives and integrals (or integrals and integrals).  i was going for a swift, compact answer that spoke to the (assumed) level of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I = \int_\mathbb{R} x^n \cos (k x) \exp ( -ax^2) ~dx$, and

$J = \int_\mathbb{R} x^n \sin (k x) \exp ( -ax^2) ~dx$

\begin{align*}
R := I + iJ &= \int_\mathbb{R} x^n \exp( ikx) \exp(-ax^2) ~dx \\
& = \int_\mathbb{R} x^n \exp\left( -a (x^2 - \frac{ik}{a}x -\frac{k^2}{4a^2} + \frac{k^2}{4a^2} \right) ~dx \\
&=e^{-k^2/4a} \int_\mathbb{R} x^n\exp\left(-a (x-\mu)^2 \right) ~dx
\end{align*}

Where $\mu = \frac{ik}{2a}$, $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Your formula (i) is valid in this regime, and you can solve out for the answer by taking the real part of $R$.